# zookeeper Retry policy not work if deploying project to weblogic server

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator, retrypolicy

I used Curator to newClient, and set retry policy, but if the connection string is wrong, retry connected will always running until out of memory, but I want the program exit once retry 3 times.

```
RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new ExponentialBackoffRetry(1000, 3);
CuratorFrameworkFactory.newClient(zkAddress,retryPolicy);
CuratorFrameworkFactory.builder().connectString(zkAddress)
    .sessionTimeoutMs(5000).connectionTimeoutMs(12000)
        .retryPolicy(retryPolicy).build();

09:03:18.810 [main-SendThread(0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181)] INFO      org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server     0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL     (unknown error)
09:03:19.825 [main-SendThread(0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181)] WARN      org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session 0x0 for server null, unexpected error,     closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(Unknown Source)
at o    rg.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxnSocketNIO.doTransport(ClientCnxnSocketNIO.java:361)
at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1081)
```